# Visual Studio Code remembering old/wrong open editors?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Previous searches for Visual Studio Code show responses for not remembering any open editors, or the opposite, but I seem to be having a novel problem. Within the same workspace, closing VSC and reopening (e.g. after a restart) will reopen some editor windows but they are often files that I had worked in and closed in the past, not the files I had open when VSC was shut down. The `Restore Windows` setting is set to all. `Limit: Enabled` for the amount of editors allowed to be open is not checked. Autosave is enabled.

Do I need to be manually saving my workspace? Is there some other obvious setting I'm missing?